# Question about the while loop for supermarket checkout case

Tags: python

I tried to make simple codes for supermarket checkout, but I have an issue with the while loop statement. Please check the code below and picture I sent.

I don't know why after I input "n", it does not go back to the loop.

```
def start():
  quan = 1
  price = 0
  end = False
  total = 0
  while end == False:
    food = (input("Enter your food: "))
    quan = int(input("Enter quantative: "))
    price = float(input("Price of food: "))
    disscount = float(input("Do you have disscount? enter '0' for no disccount. "))
    end = input("Finish? y or n: ")
    sum = price * quan
    sub_total = sum - (sum * disscount * 0.01)
    total += sub_total
    if end == "y":  
      print("Total price is ", total)
      end = True
    elif end == "n": 
      end = False
    else: 
      again = input("Wrong message! Do you want to try again? enter 'y' to try again or 'n' to end: ")
    if again == "y":  
      return start()
    elif again == "n":
      print("Bye!")
      break 

start()
```

[image]

Comment: Because before it has the chance to go back to the loop, there is an error.

Comment: You are imposing an if condition on ```again``` irrespective of whether you take an input for ```again``` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `if again` block needs to be indented:

```
else: 
  again = input("Wrong message! Do you want to try again? enter 'y' to try again or 'n' to end: ")
  if again == "y":  
    return start()
  elif again == "n":
    print("Bye!")
    break
```

Otherwise, you hit your `if` statement without necessarily having defined `again`. If it is not defined, you get the error you cite.

Comment: Great, that helps me a lot.

Comment: In addition, how to show all the foods I input?

Comment: @ken I'm not sure that I understand your follow-up question? It might bear being it's own, new question. Also, if a comment or response helps you out, definitely vote it up! And accept answers that resolve your issue. You will earn reputation and unlock more great help on StackOverflow!